# Check on array created in map()

Tags: javascript, arrays

`map()` returns an array as a result (`resultArr`). Is it possible to perform checks on the 'intermediatly' created array (`intermediateArr`) within the map function? Somewhere, the `resultArr` muste be stored so that the results of the `map()` function can be concatenated or something. Is it possible to access it?

Let's assume I want to push values to an array, if they are not included. I could do something like

```
someArr.map(item => {
    let resultArr= [];
    if(!resultArr.includes(item)) {
        resultArr.push(item);
    }
```

However, map already creates an array. It would be a 'waste' not using it. So something like

```
const resultArr = someArr.map(item => {
    if(!intermediateArr.includes(item)) {
        return item
    }
```

Where `intermediateArr` is the Array that gets updated after each iteration from the `map()` function, the array, that finally is `resultArr`

Comment: No. You can however filter the array returned from map.

Comment: What is `intermediateArr`? It not defined in your code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I guess he means the array which is created by map function internally.

Comment: @MohammadUsman your right.

Comment: What you really are looking for is `Array.from(new Set(someArr))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the "intermediate" array is internal to the `map` implementation.

You can however use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for what you want. A *map* explicitly *maps* each element of an array to another value; the result always has the same length as the input. A *reduction* is very explicitly what you're looking for; you *reduce* or *transform* the array into something else.

```
someArr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (!acc.includes(item)) {
        acc.push(item);
    }
    return acc;
}, [])
```

Comment: Please note that while this is indeed more explicit, this becomes significantly slower than `Array.from(new Set(array))` when the array gets bigger : [https://jsperf.com/array-duplicates-removal](https://jsperf.com/array-duplicates-removal)

Comment: @Logar For this particular case, sure, there are better ways to *deduplicate* an array. This is pointing out the more general approach of `map` vs. `reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

For getting unique values, you could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5],
    unique = Array.from(new Set(array));

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `map`, you can simply use a for loop to access the **intermediately** created array.

```js
let someArr = [1,2,4,1,5];
const resultArr = [];
for(let item of someArr) {
  if(!resultArr.includes(item)) resultArr.push(item);
}
console.log(resultArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce((intermediateArr, el) => {}, [])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead, where `intermediateArr` is the array that is build up while the function is running.

If for example you want to check the items in every iteration, you could use something like this:

```js
let someArr = [1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,8,9]


let resultArr = someArr.reduce((intermediateArr, item) => {
    if(!intermediateArr.includes(item)) {
        intermediateArr.push(item)
    }
    return intermediateArr;
}, [])


console.log(resultArr.toString())  // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```